# error expected identifier before string constant when defining enum in c

Tags: c, enums

I am new to C, I am trying define a enum like this:

```
enum PrimaryColor {"red","yellow","blue"}; /* can only be set to red yello or blue */
```

but when i try to compile i get this error

```
error expected identifier before string constant
```

full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    enum PrimaryColor {"red","yellow","blue"}; /* can only be set to red yello or blue */
    /* enums use a number to represent the value under the hood and we can sepcify a number that represents the value
    ex:
    */
    enum Directions {"right","left","up","down"=100}; /* here down is reprecented by a 100 /*

    /* when you specify the number reprecenting the value the number next to it will be the number before +1
    ex:
    */


    enum Directions {"right","left"=7,"down","up"}; /* left is reprecented by 7 so the number reprecenting the value(down) next to it is reprecented by 8 */
    enum Directions {"right","left"=17,"down","up"}; /* left is reprecented by 7 so the number reprecenting the value(down) next to it is reprecented by 18 */

}


}
```

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enums are not strings you can define them like this

```
enum PrimaryColor {Red, Yellow, Blue};
```

and use them like this

```
PrimaryColor.Red; //this is = 1
```

I susggest you read up on enums : [good starting place](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/enumeration-enum-c/)

Comment: thanks it is a little confusing moving from python to c